# How to make two Python programs communicate?

Tags: python, sockets, irc, interprocess

I have two Python programs, one is a IRC bot, using sockets to connect to an IRC server.

This program has a loop that reads every PRIVMSG from an specific channel.

The second program should get whatever the first program outputs (the PRIVMSG in this case) and runs functions with it.

So, it's basically:

```
while 1:
    data = irc.recv(2048)
    if data.find("PRIVMSG " + current_channel + " :") != -1:
        send_to_second_program(data)
```

the second program is

```
while 1:
    data = get_from_first_program()
    do_stuff(data)
```

Is there a way to make this happen without using modules? The two programs should be separate.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this. Your particular requirements would have to be used to narrow them down.

Comment: If they reside on the same machine, use [modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: @SiHa that's what I'm doing right now. I need it to happen on runtime, though.

Comment: Please show us some code to demonstrate your problem - see how to write a [mcve]. At the moment it is not possible to answer your problem, because it is very unclear what you actually want to achieve. Also you may be asking the wrong question :)

Comment: If they need to be separate processes, consider pipes and signals. If on separate machines (maybe tomorrow) sockets, rpc, REST...

Comment: @SiHa I added some code.

Comment: Much improved from original post. Good job @GabrielHuwe!

Comment: Why you don't want to use message queue?

Comment: @mrvol I looked into them, and Redis looks like exactly what I wanted. Maybe a bit overkill for programs that won't use lots of its features anyway, but thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Although you could use literally dozens of ways to communicate and you provide no context or requirements, I assume that you are working on a small project. I would recommend you to use **rpc** (remote procedure call). Using rpc you can call Python functions of another application as if it is a function available locally. Check out some rpc library for Python, like http://www.zerorpc.io/, which seems more than enough for your use case.

There are some downsides to using rpc, which you can read about in the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962436/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-rpc-with-respect-to-message-passing) for example, but if the scope is limited I think this is one of easiest, non-hack, ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both programs are in the same directory, you can import the other file using `import`

For example, consider a file `a.py`. To import it in another file `b.py` use `import a` Then use `a.something` to access something defined in file `a.py`

Comment: I am doing this right now.  However, I need it to happen in runtime.

Answer (score -1):

1. Over JSON (Rest API). It's service oriented architecture. So, you can very scale your application.
2. Over [Message queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) It's scaleable too, but it's not very reliability.

Comment: There are some *very* reliable message queues. Why do you say they're unreliable?

Comment: First of all, they send and receive message. Second off all, either they may be reliable and persistent or not. It isn't its primary function. I mean, for example, subscriber is down (a few time), but it have skipped a few messages. These messages can broke your logic. For example, you may forget to give money from account. There is a good comparison message queues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731233/activemq-or-rabbitmq-or-zeromq-or